# How to get a active file/Application Complete path with file Extension

Tags: c#, directory, winapp

i am trying to track active Application/File on my system using Windows application(c#).

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

            if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            {
                return Buff.ToString() + " " + handle;
            }
            return null;
        }


        private string GetActiveWindowPath()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            int handleint = int.Parse(handle + "");
            SHDocVw.ShellWindows explorer = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

            //var xy = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium();

            var xpl = explorer.Cast<SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium>().Where(hwnd => hwnd.HWND == handleint).FirstOrDefault();
            if (xpl != null)
            {
                string path = new Uri(xpl.LocationURL).LocalPath;
                return ("location:" + xpl.LocationName + " path:" + path);
            }
            return "HWND" + handleint;
        }
```

But by using the above code i only getting file title not the complete file name with extension and by using other method i am just getting folder info.

But i am trying to get the file extension with path
**Eg: D:\New Folder\sampleFile.txt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static string GetMainModuleFilepath(int processId)
    {
        string wmiQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
        {
            using (var results = searcher.Get())
            {
                ManagementObject mo = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (mo != null)
                {
                    return (string)mo["CommandLine"];
                }
            }
        }
        Process testProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        return null;
    }
```

by using this function you will get a string like

"c:..\notepade.exe" D:\New Folder\sampleFile.txt"

after that split as you like to get the path.
I have written this code for office 2007 you guys can debug and find the proper path for the higher versions.